# Trade stocks in USA

Tags: united-states, stocks, options, non-resident

What are the conditions for foreign citizens (and non-residents) to trade on American exchanges?
I believe it's possible, but don't know the conditions...

Comment: What country are you in ? As far as I know your broker should allow it and you need to fill up a W8BEN form.

Comment: I'm in Serbia, but that's not much relevant, since I'd like to open an account in American brokerage firm (if possible) - I believe they have the best technical conditions

Comment: In that case it is quite simple. Try registering and go though their terms and conditions. It should be mentioned in there. Or best try contacting them and ask for clarifications.

Comment: Point is - I'm not ready NOW, so I'm reluctant to chose a broker and contact them without being ready to act immediately. Still, I'd like to know (at least approximately) in advance. That's the reason I've chosen to inform myself this way...

Comment: You are going around in circles. Asking for information doesn't mean you need to register with them and they cannot make you to open an account.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this from the UK. It was relatively easy, you just need to apply in advance and fill in a W8BEN form which allows you to hold US stocks as a foreign national.

You will want to do this in advance as it can take a short while to go through. I did this with Barclays Stockbrokers but any worthwhile broker should be able to arrange this for you. Even if you're not ready now, there is no reason not to sign up as brokers won't charge you to open an account and there aren't any rules saying that once you have an account you must buy stocks within a specific time period etc.